# Circumvent Error 414 on HTTP POST using python requests

Tags: python, rest, http, post, python-requests

I am using python requests HTTP POST to send a data to a certain third-party website I do not own. But I can't get it to work because I am getting 414 status code.

```
url = "http://someurl.com"
headers = {
   'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
}
params = {'input': "Lorem ipsum... very long string"}
result = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(result.status_code)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: That's an error from their server - you can't fix it on your end.

Can you use a shorter string? (B/c 414 is "URL too long to process")

Comment: Are you sure you don't to pass `params` as the "data" eg. `requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)`

Comment: @John La Rooy, it worked for params for a limited string, now I used the data arg, and yeah, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the docs, it seems that `result = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)` should be `result = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)` (credit to John La Rooy).

IIRC the `params` flag means the params you see tacked onto the end of your url, while `data` is the POST data.

Comment: I used Firebug to find how to post the data to a site. I looked at parameters in the Request method and found an "input" parameter where I can inject data. It worked fine for up to around 1000 characters string. Now I tried with your suggestion, using data instead of params, and voila, it worked! Thanks.

Comment: @MarkAnthonyDelaCruz If this solved your problem, please consider clicking the "accept answer" button and upvote :) <3

Comment: Thank you so much bro :)